# Wiring two objects of the same type in the same entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I need a way to associate in the same entity two objects of the same type.
I have this class:

```
public class Link
{
   EndPoint1 e1;
   EndPoint2 e2;
}
```

and this class:

```
public class EndPoint
{
   public string Name;
}
```

When I use the 1 to 1 association, I get to navigation properties in the Link entity and two navigation properties in the EndPoint entity which is the same link object. How can I let the EndPoint entity use only one Link object?

Any suggestion of such design?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can have two separate many to one associations from Link to Endpoint.

Similar to this in one of my EF models:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you have a look at some Entity Framework Mapping Scenarios

the table shows different aspects of mapping... check it using this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716779.aspx)